# Importing a django model to a python file

Tags: python, django

Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

```py
import os
import sys
import django

project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('/mnt/c/WEB/codepython/PaymentForParking/index/telegram'))
sys.path.append(project_path)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "PaymentForParking.settings"
django.setup()
```

And I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PaymentForParking'`

Answer (score 0):

May this code solve your problem.

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "PaymentForParking.settings"
django.setup()
```